# Visual Studios ASPX. Using Panels to create Controls dynamically in a column

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a list filled with objects and for each object, I would like to create a new label at run-time. I would like the labels to be stacked on top of each other and not side by side.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_product.Count; i++)
{
    int labelCount = 1;
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.ID = "newLabel" + labelCount;
    newLabel.Text = list_product[i].ProductName;
    labelCount++;
    panel_test.Controls.Add(newLabel);

}
```

I've been looking everywhere and I can't find a solution.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you fix up the code indents?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  How would you like me to fix it up? I'm pretty new to this stuff

Comment: This is done in the front-end with CSS. It has nothing to do with the C# code and how the Label is generated.